flutter_lints any which doesn't exist (authorization failed), version solving failed
i try launch default new flutter project in android studio , and i do it step by step like
document   but always get this error

use flutter doctor and all things good ,but i always get this error even for flutter packages get or flutter update
this is my default pubspec.yaml without any change
name: untitled7
description: "A new Flutter project."

publish_to: 'none' 



version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.3 <4.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter



  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

 
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1


flutter:


  uses-material-design: true

and analysis_options :
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

linter:


  rules:

even in github people post this issue , but there is no good answer , after some research i try so many ways like change version of flutter sdk or for some people remove version of  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1 be like  flutter_lints: did work but still didn't work for me

Would it be appropriate to record you typing that command and showing the error? If you don't think so, please just send the cmd showing your directory (blur your name too of course)

As long as you live in Iran with hard and deep sanctions from other countries, you have to set VPN.
I suggest you use Shecan if you don't have access to any VPN.
Happy Coding :)

i use fodev.org and it work for dependencies but in this case shecan solved my problem tnq

i used Proxifier and 403.online and my problem was solved :)
i think now 403.online is better than shecan

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
