fluter give this eror (Because flutter_application_1 depends on flutter_lints any which doesn't exist (authorization failed), version solving failed.)
After pub get flutter give me this error
Because flutter_application_1 depends on flutter_lints any which doesn't exist (authorization failed), version solving failed.
i dont know how to fix it
it happens after upgrade flutter and build a new app
full error
[flutter_application_1] flutter pub get --no-example
Resolving dependencies...
Because flutter_application_1 depends on flutter_lints any which doesn't exist (authorization failed), version solving failed.
Insufficient permissions to the resource at the https://pub.dev package repository.
You can modify credentials using:
dart pub token add https://pub.dev
exit code 69
i tried flutter doctor and there is no problem
also using dns and vpn but nothing happen
options.yaml
    'include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

linter:

  rules:
    # avoid_print: false  # Uncomment to disable the `avoid_print` rule
    # prefer_single_quotes: true  # Uncomment to enable the `prefer_single_quotes` rule'


pubspec.yaml
'name: flutter_application_1
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

 --build-name and --build-number, respectively.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.4 <4.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true'


check this maybe it helps! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78288711/flutter-lints-any-which-doesnt-exist-authorization-failed-version-solving-fa

flutter_lints is a public package. You shouldn't need any credentials.
Can you paste your pubspec.yaml file? (Only what you can)
Check to see you don't have a VPN connected on your device. Try running flutter pub get on another device. It might be an issue with your physical device.
